# ng-grid rowTemplate; conditionally change the height wiht ng-style

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a ng-grid , where in i need to expand the size of a row conditionally.

```
rowTemplate:'<div ng-style="row.getProperty(\'sel\') === \'0\' && {\'height\': \'300px\'}" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}" ng-cell></div>
```

Please look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tFma37Qsfwo4407qyC2a?p=preview)

I can see that the height is been increased but rows below the expanded row will not adjust.

Have anyone done anything like this. Am i doing it right or any other proper  solution ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use dynamical row heights on `ngGrid`.

This has been asked a dozen times before.

`ngGrid` simulates a table by generating a lot of positioned divs in a grid layout instead of using a `html table`.

You should use an other table directive like [trNgGrid](http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/) which uses real tables, but has all the features of `ngGrid`. It would take a lot of work to adjust the top positions of subsequent rows.

The only thing you can do in `ngGrid` is setting the `rowHeight` in `gridOptions` to an appropriate value, which would affect all rows.

Do yourself a favor and think about switching to a directive that better suits your needs. There are several around. It will save you a lot of work and you can use the native rendering speed of your browsers table drawing engine.